# How to fix this issue "Consider defining a bean of type 'repository.InterfaceName' in your configuration."

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ to learn spring boot and I encountered this issue when running the code

```
2021-09-05 12:55:48.665 ERROR 10396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in service.EmployeeService required a bean of type 'repository.EmployeeRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'repository.EmployeeRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

the project files tree looks like this:

```
├── HELP.md
├── mvnw
├── mvnw.cmd
├── my-first-project.iml
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   ├── com
│   │   │   │   └── firstproject
│   │   │   │       └── myfirstproject
│   │   │   │           └── MyFirstProjectApplication.java
│   │   │   ├── controller
│   │   │   │   └── EmployeeController.java
│   │   │   ├── model
│   │   │   │   └── Employee.java
│   │   │   ├── repository
│   │   │   │   └── EmployeeRepository.java
│   │   │   └── service
│   │   │       └── EmployeeService.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── application.properties
│   │       ├── static
│   │       └── templates
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── com
│               └── firstproject
│                   └── myfirstproject
│                       └── MyFirstProjectApplicationTests.java
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   ├── application.properties
    │   ├── com
    │   │   └── firstproject
    │   │       └── myfirstproject
    │   │           └── MyFirstProjectApplication.class
    │   ├── controller
    │   │   └── EmployeeController.class
    │   ├── model
    │   │   └── Employee.class
    │   ├── repository
    │   │   └── EmployeeRepository.class
    │   └── service
    │       └── EmployeeService.class
    ├── generated-sources
    │   └── annotations
    ├── generated-test-sources
    │   └── test-annotations
    └── test-classes
        └── com
            └── firstproject
                └── myfirstproject
                    └── MyFirstProjectApplicationTests.class
```

EmployeeController:

```java
package controller;

import model.Employee;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import service.EmployeeService;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    private final EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService) {

        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }
    @GetMapping
    public List<Employee> getEmployee(){
        return employeeService.getEmployee();
    }
}
```

EmployeeService :

```java
package service;

import model.Employee;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import repository.EmployeeRepository;

import java.util.List;


@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    @Autowired
    public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Employee> getEmployee(){

        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Employee :

```java
package model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "emp_sequence",
    sequenceName = "emp_sequence",
    allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "emp_sequence")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private LocalDate dob;
    private Float salary;

    public Employee() {
    } ...\\Getters and Setters
```

EmployeeRepository :

```java
package repository;

import model.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,Long> {

}
```

MyFirstProjectApplication:

```java
package com.firstproject.myfirstproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;



@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"repository","controller","service","model"})
//I added scanBasePackages = {"repository","controller","service","model"} because i hade the same problem with other packages and it solved it except for repository
public class MyFirstProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyFirstProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

the application properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/employee
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=*********
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

And Finaly the pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.firstproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-first-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-first-project</name>
    <description>my-first-project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am using:

- java 11
- spring boot (v2.5.4)
- Intellij IDEA 2021.2.1 ultimate edition

I had the same problem with other packages but adding `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"controller","service","model"})` solved the issue for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the packages `controller`, `repository`, `model` and `service` to `com.firstproject.myfirstproject`. With this you may get rid of `scanBasePackages = {"controller","service","model"}` and use only `@SpringBootApplication` as follows:

```java
package com.firstproject.myfirstproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyFirstProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyFirstProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned. That is why it is usually a good practice to include the main class in the base package of the project.

Comment: I have the same problem, but beans are in maven dependencies (jar)
How can workaroud Spring Injection ?
Some Service bean can't found repository class for injection.

**@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"sak.spring.repositories", "sak.spring.services","sak.spring.entities"})**
sak.spring is a DAO project Spring Boot, added to actual projet by **<dependency>** maven

Thank U.

Answer (score 6):

Well annotation scanning for Spring does not include the package repository so it does not scan the `@Repository` to add it as a spring bean. You ned to also define

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"controller","service","model", "repository"})
```

Reason for that is that the default package that spring scanns is the `com.firstproject.myfirstproject` where the `MyFirstProjectApplication.claass` exists which defines the main method that starts the spring boot application.

Considering that all other packages are outside of that package you need to define them manualy with `scanBasePackages` in order for spring to get inside those other packages like service, repository and scan for annotations and make neccessary actions.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very insightful I appreciate your explanation

Comment: @ChaabFI you can always upvote if you find answer helpful ;)